# RegEx that will find quoted strings but NOT inside HTML tags

Tags: .net, regex

I have been looking for a regular expression that will identify a quoted string in the content of an HTML page but NOT if the quotes are part of attributes of HTML tags.

Example:

```
<p id="123">This is some "quoted text" in a <span class="test">sentence.</span></p>
```

In the above line, I want to find "quoted text" string but not id="123" or class="test".

I have tried a few but none work.

The following REGEX picks up the HTML tags in the above example and excludes the sentence content...but I want it to do the opposite:

```
<[^>]+>
```

Comment: I don't think regular expressions are powerful enough to parse HTML, and understand the context of HTML.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse HTML to get useful things out of it, use [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) - it makes it fairly straightforward to do things like this.

See also: [You can't use Regex'es to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/847383)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular context, I don't think you're going to have many guarantees. There are too many options for how quoted strings can be put together within a snippet of HTML. However, based on the specific example you gave above, the following expression would find "quoted text":

```
(?<=(?:^|>)[^<>]*)"[^"]+"(?=[^<>]*(?:<|$))
```